# Batch ~dp0 doesn't work with admin rights?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd, admin-rights

I have a batch file which looks like this:

```
set OWNPATH = %~dp0

for /r %OWNPATH% %%F in (*.ocx) do ( echo %%F )
```

It correctly lists all OCX files in the same folder when I start it, but lists the OCX files in

> C:\Windows\System32

when I right-click it and select "Run as administrator".

How can I fix that? The script generally needs admin rights.

Comment: You should remove the spaces around `SET OWNPATH=%~dp0`

Comment: or even better: `set "OWNPATH=%~dp0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `set` is setting `%OWNPATH %` (note the space between `OWNPATH` and the `=`).  Therefore `%OWNPATH%` (with no space) is not defined, and `for /r %OWNPATH% %%F ...` gets expanded to `for /r  %%F`, and the `for` loop ends up looking in the current directory (which is C:\Windows\System32 when run as administrator).

Get in the habit of doing your assignments like this to avoid that common mistake:

```
set "OWNPATH=%~dp0"
```